# How to generate reports per month and per year from the database in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am creating a generation of reports per month and per year. There are 15 types of fees that I want to display the total sales per month. I have a date column in my database table with the format of (ex. 2014-09-27). I don't know how to order by it per month (from Jan-Dec) then add all the total of each fee. I have a drop down list to select the year so that I will display the reports per year and per month that depends to my selected year. Each fee in the database has a price.

database name: Registration

table name: Application

columns: DATE_APPLICATION, Barangay_Business_Permit, Business_Plate, Sanitary_Inspection_Fee, Environmental_Clearance, Barangay_Development, Building_Permit, Electrical_Inspection, Mechanical_Inspection, Plumbing_Inspection, Health_Certificate, Signage_Fee, Penalty, Barangay_Clearance, Barangay_Certification, Construction_Clearance

Comment: You need to extract month from date, put this value into an alias field and then group by on this one

Comment: @Claudio How can I extract the month from date then group by it so that I can compute the total sales of each fee per month?

Comment: In my sql exists a function for this MONTHNAMR(). This accept date as argument and RETURN name of month

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

Comment: @claudio I don't know how to do it in php by identifying the months and grouping it. I just new in php.

Comment: You can do all of the groupings in MySQL, no reason to make PHP do it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated information, You would need to pull a select based on the dates and then sum the columns grouping by the Date_Application if you want to calculate the totals for the applications by month or year. So for a monthly listing:

```
Select SUM(Barangay_Business_Permit), SUM(Business_Plate), SUM(Sanitary_Inspection_Fee),
SUM(Environmental_Clearance), SUM(Barangay_Development), SUM(Building_Permit),
SUM(Electrical_Inspection), SUM(Mechanical_Inspection), SUM(Plumbing_Inspection),
SUM(Health_Certificate), SUM(Signage_Fee), SUM(Penalty), SUM(Barangay_Clearance),
SUM(Barangay_Certification), SUM(Construction_Clearance)
from Registration.application GROUP BY MONTH(DATE_APPLICATION);
```

For a yearly listing:

```
Select SUM(Barangay_Business_Permit), SUM(Business_Plate), SUM(Sanitary_Inspection_Fee),
SUM(Environmental_Clearance), SUM(Barangay_Development), SUM(Building_Permit),
SUM(Electrical_Inspection), SUM(Mechanical_Inspection), SUM(Plumbing_Inspection),
SUM(Health_Certificate), SUM(Signage_Fee), SUM(Penalty), SUM(Barangay_Clearance),
SUM(Barangay_Certification), SUM(Construction_Clearance)
from Registration.application GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_APPLICATION);
```

If you want to use the names for the months you would use `MONTHNAME(DATE_APPLICATION)` instead.

Comment: Is that second one supposed to be YEAR( DATE )?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I made some changes to my question. I changed it to ORDER BY because I will get all the total of each rows (in order). How can I breakdown the total of each fee per month? For example I will separate the total of each fee this month and start again the computation for the next month.